# Storing v-if conditional statement in an object in Vue.js

Tags: arrays, if-statement, vue.js, conditional-statements

Is it possible to store a conditional statement in an object and dynamically add it in?

For example, I have a this code that outputs a table row with a button in it:

```
 <tr v-for="item in items">
     <td><button v-if="item.display">{{item.name}}</button>
 </tr>
```

This is my data I'm returning

```
data() {
        return {
            items : [
                {
                    name : 'Item1',
                    display : 'price >= 5',
                },
                {
                    name : 'Item2',
                    display : 'price == 10',
                },
            ],
        }
    },
```

When doing this, the logic doesn't work. The button always displays.

However, if I were to manually enter in that logic for each button. It works correctly. For example, this works:

```
<tr v-for="item in items">
     <td><button v-if="price >= 5">{{item.name}}</button>
 </tr>
```

So, in the end, my question is. Can the conditional statement be stored like that and dynamically added in, or will Vue not recognize it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technicaly, you can use functions as properties of your objects and call them:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      price: 5,
      items: [{
          name: 'Item1',
          display: (price) => price >= 5,
        },
        {
          name: 'Item2',
          display: (price) => price == 10,
        },
      ],
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  Type "10": <input v-model="price">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="item in items">
      <td><button v-if="item.display(price)">{{item.name}}</button>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

But perhaps a more Vue*y* approach would be to specify the constraints of the display in the object and have the calculation in a **method**.

The advantage here is that your `items` data is clearly serializable (e.g. to JSON), whereas in the option above that's not the case:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      price: 5,
      items: [{
          name: 'Item1',
          display: {op: 'ge', val: 5},
        },
        {
          name: 'Item2',
          display: {op: 'eq', val: 10},
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
   display(item) {
     switch(item.display.op) {
       case 'eq': return this.price == item.display.val;
        case 'gt': return this.price > item.display.val;
        case 'lt': return this.price < item.display.val;
        case 'ge': return this.price >= item.display.val;
        case 'le': return this.price <= item.display.val;
        default: return false;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  Type "10": <input v-model="price">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="item in items">
      <td><button v-if="display(item)">{{item.name}}</button>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think acdcjunior provided a good direct answer on this question. I'm not sure if I should add something here in case if question was totally technical about that specific feature of Vue.

However, I just want to notice, that data is not a good place to store display information. More common situation is when you have data with own prices:

```
data() {
    return {
      price: 5,

      items: [{
          name: 'Item1',
          price: 5,
        },
        {
          name: 'Item2',
          price: 10,
        },
      ],
    }
  }
```

And very common case is when you need to render only some subset from your items. That scenario described well in vue docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Displaying-Filtered-Sorted-Results

Hope it wasn't excess :)

Also, back to your question itself:

> Can the conditional statement be stored like that and dynamically
> added in, or will Vue not recognize it that way?

I think short answer is "No".

Because when you pass `item.condition` (which is a string) to `v-if`, result of evaluating your expression (which is `"price === 5"` for example) just will be checked for trueness -> and non empty string is always `true`. There is no some `eval` analogs for strings.

But when expression is a function (as in acdcjunior's example) **result** of its execution will be resulting expression which should be checked.